# How to find merges between two git commits?

Tags: git

Given two git commit hashes, how do you lookup the branch names of all associated merges in between those commits?

I'm trying to write a script to collect some statistics about which branches have been merged into a specified target branch between two given dates.

I know you can get a list of all branches merged into a target branch with a command like:

```
git branch --merged <target_branch>
```

but how do you limit it to a certain range of commits?

Comment: The notion of "between" itself is fuzzy (due to branch-and-merge structures within the DAG)—perhaps you want the equivalent of `git rev-list --ancestry-path ^exclude include`, but perhaps not—but once you have the set of all commits to consider as "between", `--min-parents=2` aka `--merges` (as in Andrew Miner's answer) will select such commits.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use the `git log` command with the `--merges` flag.  So, for example, if you want to find all the merges between `release-1.0` and `release-2.0`, you'd say:

```
git log release-1.0..release-2.0 --merges
```

Comment: This seems to include all logs between two commits, not just those merged into the target branch.

Comment: That's very odd... I definitely see it limiting to only merges when I use the `--merges` argument.  Also, here's the [official documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log---merges).  What platform / git version are you using?

Comment: Yes, it limits it to merges, but it shows merges to all branches, not just my target branch.

Comment: I see what you're getting at.  As torek mentions in his comment, figuring out exactly what is "in" a given branch is a bit wooly in git.  I've played around a bit, and I can't do better than torek's suggestion in his comment above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add the name of the branch of interest to @Andrew Miners answer. I've used something like the following to check for differences between two commits on the origin to generate release notes:

```
git fetch
git log --merges --first-parent --oneline origin 3c06b3544a9f86d3f0cbe57e0ef6dafda850945c..caf05bfb706ae958f73b8bbe997b0c431ffbdb9c
```